# environment.yml: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I would like to install a Conda environment with Pip dependencies from an `environment.yml` file which I have included at the bottom of this post.

However, I get the following error:

```
Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-8vvj24wt\\normalizer.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

The `pip-uninstall-8vvj24wt` directory appears during installation of the Pip dependencies. How do I resolve this?

```
name: nb_classification_py310
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - aiohttp=3.8.4=py310h8d17308_0
  - aiohttp-retry=2.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - aiosignal=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - amqp=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - antlr-python-runtime=4.9.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - anyio=3.5.0=py310haa95532_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - argon2-cffi=21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - asttokens=2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - async-timeout=4.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - asyncssh=2.13.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - atpublic=3.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attrs=22.2.0=pyh71513ae_0
  - babel=2.11.0=py310haa95532_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - backports=1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.12.2=py310haa95532_0
  - billiard=3.6.4.0=py310h8d17308_3
  - black=23.3.0=py310h5588dad_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py310h9128911_0
  - brotli=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310h8d17308_1005
  - bzip2=1.0.8=he774522_0
  - ca-certificates=2023.5.7=h56e8100_0
  - celery=5.2.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - certifi=2023.5.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310h628cb3f_3
  - click=8.1.3=win_pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - click-didyoumean=0.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click-plugins=1.1.1=py_0
  - click-repl=0.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=py310haa95532_0
  - comm=0.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - configobj=5.0.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - contourpy=1.0.5=py310h59b6b97_0
  - cryptography=38.0.4=py310h52f42fa_0
  - cudatoolkit=11.2.2=h933977f_10
  - cudnn=8.1.0.77=h3e0f4f4_0
  - cycler=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - debugpy=1.5.1=py310hd77b12b_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - dictdiffer=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - diskcache=5.6.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - distro=1.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dpath=2.1.5=py310h5588dad_0
  - dulwich=0.21.3=py310h8d17308_0
  - dvc=2.55.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dvc-data=0.47.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dvc-http=2.30.2=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - dvc-objects=0.21.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dvc-render=0.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dvc-ssh=2.22.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dvc-studio-client=0.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dvc-task=0.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - eigen=3.3.7=h59b6b97_1
  - entrypoints=0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - et_xmlfile=1.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - executing=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ffmpeg=4.2.2=he774522_0
  - fftw=3.3.9=h2bbff1b_1
  - filelock=3.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - flatten-dict=0.4.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - flufl.lock=7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - fonttools=4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=ha860e81_0
  - frozenlist=1.3.3=py310h8d17308_0
  - fsspec=2023.4.0=pyh1a96a4e_0
  - funcy=2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - future=0.18.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h8cc25b3_3
  - gitdb=4.0.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gitpython=3.1.31=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - glib=2.69.1=h5dc1a3c_2
  - grandalf=0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.18.5=h9e645db_0
  - gstreamer=1.18.5=hd78058f_0
  - hdf5=1.10.6=h1756f20_1
  - hydra-core=1.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - icc_rt=2022.1.0=h6049295_2
  - icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
  - idna=3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib-metadata=6.5.0=pyha770c72_0
  - importlib_resources=5.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=haa95532_3556
  - ipykernel=6.19.2=py310h9909e9c_0
  - ipympl=0.9.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ipython=8.12.0=py310haa95532_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - ipywidgets=8.0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - iterative-telemetry=0.0.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jedi=0.18.1=py310haa95532_1
  - jinja2=3.1.2=py310haa95532_0
  - joblib=1.1.1=py310haa95532_0
  - jpeg=9e=h2bbff1b_1
  - json5=0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jsonschema=4.17.3=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py310haa95532_8
  - jupyter_client=8.1.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_console=6.6.3=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_core=5.3.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyter_server=1.23.4=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab=3.5.3=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=py_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.22.0=py310haa95532_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.5=py310haa95532_0
  - kiwisolver=1.4.4=py310hd77b12b_0
  - kombu=5.2.4=py310h5588dad_2
  - krb5=1.19.4=h5b6d351_0
  - lerc=3.0=hd77b12b_0
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h2bbff1b_7
  - libclang13=14.0.6=default_h8e68704_1
  - libdeflate=1.17=h2bbff1b_0
  - libffi=3.4.2=hd77b12b_6
  - libgit2=1.6.4=hc6d37dd_0
  - libiconv=1.16=h2bbff1b_2
  - libogg=1.3.5=h2bbff1b_1
  - libpng=1.6.39=h8cc25b3_0
  - libprotobuf=3.20.3=h23ce68f_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h62dcd97_0
  - libssh2=1.10.0=h680486a_3
  - libtiff=4.5.0=h6c2663c_2
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=he774522_0
  - libwebp=1.2.4=hbc33d0d_1
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=h2bbff1b_1
  - libxml2=2.10.3=h0ad7f3c_0
  - libxslt=1.1.37=h2bbff1b_0
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hcfcfb64_4
  - lxml=4.9.2=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h2bbff1b_0
  - markdown-it-py=2.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - matplotlib=3.7.1=py310haa95532_1
  - matplotlib-base=3.7.1=py310h4ed8f06_1
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=py310haa95532_0
  - mdurl=0.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py310h2bbff1b_1000
  - mkl=2021.4.0=haa95532_640
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py310ha0764ea_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - multidict=6.0.4=py310h8d17308_0
  - munkres=1.1.4=py_0
  - mypy_extensions=1.0.0=pyha770c72_0
  - nanotime=0.5.2=py_0
  - nbclassic=0.5.5=py310haa95532_0
  - nbclient=0.5.13=py310haa95532_0
  - nbconvert=6.5.4=py310haa95532_0
  - nbformat=5.7.0=py310haa95532_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.6=py310haa95532_0
  - networkx=3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - notebook=6.5.4=py310haa95532_0
  - notebook-shim=0.2.2=py310haa95532_0
  - numexpr=2.8.4=py310hd213c9f_0
  - numpy-base=1.23.5=py310h04254f7_0
  - omegaconf=2.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - opencv=4.6.0=py310h4ed8f06_3
  - openpyxl=3.0.10=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - openssl=1.1.1t=hcfcfb64_0
  - orjson=3.8.10=py310h48ea969_0
  - pandas=1.5.3=py310h4ed8f06_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pathlib2=2.3.7.post1=py310h5588dad_2
  - pathspec=0.11.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pcre=8.45=hd77b12b_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pillow=9.4.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pip=23.0.1=py310haa95532_0
  - platformdirs=3.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ply=3.11=py310haa95532_0
  - prometheus_client=0.14.1=py310haa95532_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.38=pyha770c72_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.38=hd8ed1ab_0
  - psutil=5.9.5=py310h8d17308_0
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pydot=1.2.4=py_0
  - pygit2=1.12.0=py310h8d17308_0
  - pygments=2.15.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pygtrie=2.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=23.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=py310haa95532_0
  - pyqt=5.15.7=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyqt5-sip=12.11.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - pyrsistent=0.18.0=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyh0701188_6
  - python=3.10.10=h966fe2a_2
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.16.2=py310haa95532_0
  - python-gssapi=1.8.2=py310hf7a0c3d_1
  - python_abi=3.10=2_cp310
  - pytz=2022.7=py310haa95532_0
  - pywin32=304=py310h00ffb61_2
  - pywin32-on-windows=0.1.0=pyh07e9846_2
  - pywinpty=2.0.10=py310h5da7b33_0
  - pyyaml=6.0=py310h8d17308_5
  - pyzmq=23.2.0=py310hd77b12b_0
  - qt-main=5.15.2=he8e5bd7_8
  - qt-webengine=5.15.9=hb9a9bb5_5
  - qtconsole=5.4.2=py310haa95532_0
  - qtpy=2.2.0=py310haa95532_0
  - qtwebkit=5.212=h2bbfb41_5
  - requests=2.28.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - rich=13.3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ruamel=1.0=py310haa95532_2
  - ruamel.yaml=0.17.21=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - ruamel.yaml.clib=0.2.6=py310h2bbff1b_1
  - scikit-learn=1.2.0=py310hd77b12b_1
  - scipy=1.9.3=py310h86744a3_0
  - scmrepo=1.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - seaborn=0.12.2=py310haa95532_0
  - send2trash=1.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - setuptools=66.0.0=py310haa95532_0
  - shortuuid=1.0.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - shtab=1.6.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sip=6.6.2=py310hd77b12b_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - smmap=3.0.5=pyh44b312d_0
  - sniffio=1.2.0=py310haa95532_1
  - soupsieve=2.4=py310haa95532_0
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h2bbff1b_0
  - sqltrie=0.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sshfs=2023.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - stack_data=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - tabulate=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - terminado=0.17.1=py310haa95532_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.2.0=pyh0d69192_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=py310haa95532_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h2bbff1b_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomlkit=0.11.7=pyha770c72_0
  - tornado=6.2=py310h2bbff1b_0
  - tqdm=4.65.0=py310h9909e9c_0
  - traitlets=5.7.1=py310haa95532_0
  - typing=3.10.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing-extensions=4.5.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.5.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h04d1e81_0
  - ucrt=10.0.22621.0=h57928b3_0
  - urllib3=1.26.15=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vine=5.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - voluptuous=0.13.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - vs2015_runtime=14.34.31931=h4c5c07a_10
  - wcwidth=0.2.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py310haa95532_1
  - websocket-client=0.58.0=py310haa95532_4
  - wheel=0.38.4=py310haa95532_0
  - widgetsnbextension=4.0.5=py310haa95532_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_6
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - xz=5.2.10=h8cc25b3_1
  - yaml=0.2.5=h8ffe710_2
  - yarl=1.8.2=py310h8d17308_0
  - zc.lockfile=3.0.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zeromq=4.3.4=hd77b12b_0
  - zipp=3.15.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=hcfcfb64_4
  - zstd=1.5.5=hd43e919_0
  - pip:
      - absl-py==1.4.0
      - astunparse==1.6.3
      - cachetools==5.3.0
      - charset-normalizer==3.1.0
      - dvclive==2.6.4
      - flatbuffers==23.3.3
      - gast==0.4.0
      - google-auth==2.17.3
      - google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
      - google-pasta==0.2.0
      - grpcio==1.54.0
      - h5py==3.8.0
      - keras==2.10.0
      - keras-preprocessing==1.1.2
      - libclang==16.0.0
      - markdown==3.4.3
      - markupsafe==2.1.2
      - numpy==1.24.2
      - oauthlib==3.2.2
      - opt-einsum==3.3.0
      - packaging==23.1
      - protobuf==3.19.6
      - pyasn1==0.4.8
      - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
      - requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
      - rsa==4.9
      - tensorboard==2.10.1
      - tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
      - tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
      - tensorflow==2.10.1
      - tensorflow-estimator==2.10.0
      - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
      - termcolor==2.2.0
      - werkzeug==2.2.3
      - wrapt==1.15.0
prefix: C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\nb_classification_py310
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to find a delete the package responsible for creating the `normalizer.exe` which was `charset-normalizer==3.1.0`. Likely conflicting with one that has been installed as a dependency by another package.